# FileStream IsAsync C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-webapi, filestream

Please explain what will give the `IsAsync = true` property in `FileStream`. [Documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.isasync?view=net-7.0)

This variant uses this property

```
    await using FileStream fileStream = new(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, 
                                                  FileShare.Read, 4096, true);
    await using MemoryStream memoryStream = new(bytes);
    await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream, cancellationToken);
```

In this version without it

```
await using FileStream fileStream = new(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
await using MemoryStream memoryStream = new(bytes);
await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream, cancellationToken);
```

How will the behavior change? It is not clear to me why I should use it at all if I make a `memoryStream.CopyToAsync`.

This property allows you to open a file in some special asynchronous thread, does it belong to some other thread pool?

If we are talking about the Web API, does this property give me an advantage similar to the usual asynchronous calls in which the main thread is released?

Comment: Unless you explicitly specify `useAsync: true` in the ctor call-site the `FileStream`'s 
`...Async` methods will be "fake-async": that is, they'll block the thread just like the non-`...Async` methods, which you _don't wan't_ in ASP.NET (or server-side scenarios in general) because it means the system can't use that thread-block time _productively_ by re-using those threads to service other requests.

Comment: _"This property allows you to open a file in some special asynchronous thread, does it belong to some other thread pool?"_ - "`async`" does not mean that at all, see here: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html